# Run Angular from C# - NUnit testing

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, nunit

In the solution we have an API, Angular app and NUnit tests project. I have the task to test the UI of the angular app from NUnit test. Is there a way to run angular app from the setup of the test?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium WebDriver for those purposes. If it is configured correctly, you will be able to open a new web browser inside your NUnit test and check the Angular app there.

Comment: Can you set that webDriver to call basically "ng s" on the client app?

Comment: I am not familiar with Angular app architecture, so I am not able to answer your question. The main idea of WebDriver is just creating the new browser tab, just as you do it manually with your browser. You still should deploy your app somewhere, then you will be able to connect to it using WebDriver